# update recrod according to datetime in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have table name "info" with column "lastupdated" (datatype is datetime),I just want to update all 
record where "updatedOn" is not equal to currentdate/today's date

Here is my table "info"

```
id      status      lastupdated
1       1           2010-01-01 13:25:02 
2       NULL        2010-01-03 14:05:02
3       1           2010-01-02 13:30:01
```

I tried with following query but not working,Where i am wrong ?

```
UPDATE info SET status = NULL
WHERE lastupdated != '2020-01-03'
```

Comment: Note that DATE() cannot use an index. So, `NOT BETWEEN '2020-01-03 00:00:00' AND '2020-01-03 23:59:59'` would be more performant (if said index were available)

Comment: I have downvoted because if I can find at least 5 duplicates to close with, then the question is probably "under-researched".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try with Date() function

```
UPDATE info SET status = NULL WHERE DATE(lastupdated) != '2020-01-03'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE()` function of mysql  to compare

```
UPDATE info SET status = NULL
WHERE DATE(lastupdated ) != '2020-01-03'
```